# Find a Morita equivalent finite cell DG category

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories, dg-categories

I am trying to understand the following statement:

> Suppose that $\mathcal{E}$ is a pre-triangulated proper DG category with a full exceptional collection. Then $\mathcal{E}$ is Morita equivalent to a directed DG category $\mathcal{E}'$, i.e. $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{E}')=\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\}$ where $\mathcal{E}'(X_i,X_j)=0$ for $i>j$, and $\mathcal{E}'(X_i,X_j)=k$. Moreover, we may assume that $\mathcal{E}'$ is a finite cell DG category (e.g. by replacing $\mathcal{E'}$ with the bar-cobar construction of the minimal $A_{\infty}$-model of $\mathcal{E}'$.)

What I understood now is since $\mathcal{E}$ is pretriangulated so $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{E}^{\mathrm{pre-tr}})$ is a triangulated category so we can find an exceptional collection $X_1,\cdots, X_n$. If we take the cateory $\mathcal{E}'$ as above, then how can we show these two are Morita equivalent?

As for the second part, I think it says, by the bar-cobar construction, we can find a finite cell category Morita equivalent to $\mathcal{E}'$. I was wondering if there any (detailed) reference for this statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think maybe you mean $\mathcal{E}(E_i,E_i) = k$. The result follows from the general theory of derived Morita equivalence since the full exceptional collection gives a generator of the category. A little googling finds this reference: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2015-143-05/S0002-9939-2014-12420-8/S0002-9939-2014-12420-8.pdf